# Python JSON parsing handling missing value

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am working on Python 3 and storing only required data from a JSON payload, sometimes the payload is not consistent and the values I am storing may not be present. My code works fine when all the values are present in the payload, sharing a sample data and code. I would like to assing Null or None when a value is not present in the payload. Can anyone please help me in resolving this issue.
**Sample Data**

```
data = 
{
            "Session": {
                "@displayName": "1212",
                "@id": 1212,
                "anchorIpAddress": {
                    "address": "0.0.0.0"
                },
                "apMacAddress": {
                    "octets": "111111111"
                },
                "algorithm": "OPENSYSTEM",
                "bytesReceived": 1000,
                "bytesSent": 100
            }
        },
        {
            "Session": {
                "@displayName": "1111",
                "@id": 1111,
                "anchorIpAddress": {
                    "address": "0.0.0.0"
                },
                "algorithm": "OPENSYSTEM",
                "bytesReceived": 234,
                "bytesSent": 20
            }
        },
        {
            "Session": {
                "@displayName": "1313",
                "@id": 1313,
                "apMacAddress": {
                    "octets": "14312312"
                },
                "algorithm": "OPENSYSTEM",
                "bytesReceived": 39735,
                "bytesSent": 8308
            }
        }
}
```

**Code**

```
        clients = json.loads(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
        client1 = {}

    for client in clients:
        client1["display"] = client['Session']['@display']
        client1["id"] = client['Session']['@id']
        client1["anchorIpAddress"] = client['Session']['anchorIpAddress']['address']
        client1["apMacAddress"] = client['Session']['apMacAddress']['octets']
        print(client1)
```

**Error**

```
   client1["apMacAddress"] = client['clientSessionsDTO']['apMacAddress']['octets']
   KeyError: 'apMacAddress'
```

**Expected Result**

```
{
display: 1212,
id: 1212,
anchorIpAddress: "0.0.0.0",
apMacAddress: "111111111"
},
{
display: 1212,
id: 1212,
anchorIpAddress: "0.0.0.0",
apMacAddress: Null
},
{
display: 1313,
id: 1313,
anchorIpAddress: Null,
apMacAddress: "14312312"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe

```
client1["apMacAddress"] = client.get('clientSessionsDTO',{}).get('apMacAddress',{}).get('octets', None)
```

could help?